# Django query_set order_by default field if ordering field is an empty string

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query_set that I want to order by `Lower('title')`. However, for some elements, `title` is blank (`blank=True`). So, when I sort, those elements are rightfully are on top. However, all elements, no matter what, have a `default_title`. So, I want to use an element's `default_title` in the sorting if `title` is blank.

`.order_by(Lower('title') if Lower('title') != '' else Lower('website_title'))` does not work

Comment: Can you share models and view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
query_set = query_set.annotate(order_title=Coalesce(
        Case(
            When(title__exact='', then=None),
            When(title__isnull=False, then='title'),
            default=None,
            output_field=CharField()
        ),'default_title')).order_by('order_title')
```